# Entity metadata wrapper - how to get field value, NOT key

Tags: 7, entities

I hhave `field_something` which is a select field with multiple options:

```
key1|Value 1
key2|Value 2
```

I'm trying to get the value of this field using the Entity metadata wrapper.

`$wrapper->field_something->value();`

This will return the key, not the value as defined in the node's fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the key _is_ the value of the field as stored in the database. If you want the value as displayed you'll have to use the Field API to get the settings for the field. I think you'll find it somewhere in what's returned from field_info_field().

Comment: Why don't you use [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to see what are the available options of the `$wrapper` variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use `$wrapper->field_something->label()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$list = $wrapper->field_machine_name->optionsList();
```

I hope it helps you!